# Is /min a valid switch for cmd.exe in Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, command-line-arguments, parameters

I'm looking at a few batch files (.bat), and they use use `/min` as a switch for `cmd.exe`.  Looking at several references, I don't see `/min` as a parameter for `cmd.exe`.

Is `/min` a valid switch for `cmd.exe` in Windows 7-10?

Comment: No it's not. However its a valid switch for the `start` command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's used by the start command. For example if you want to start a program minimized you could use:

```
cmd.exe /c start /min notepad.exe
```